# How to pass value from one custom element to another element in Polymerjs 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a custom element element1.html in which we use iron-ajax to call the service,data received from the service is used to populate the dropdown menu

```
<dom-module id="element1">
<iron-ajax auto
    url="../sites.json"    
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    ></iron-ajax>
<paper-dropdown-menu-light label="select site" noink no-animations>
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content sitedropdown">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
        <a class="sitelist" on-tap="testclick" data-cus$="{{item.keyValue}}"  href$="{{baseUrl}}site/{{item.keyValue}}" tabindex="-1">         
          <paper-item raised>{{item.Name}}</paper-item>
        </a>         
      </template>          
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu-light>

<script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'element1',
     properties: {     
        },
        handleResponse:function(e,request){
       this.data=e.detail.response;
        },
    testclick : function(e){
      console.log(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-cus'));
      this.keyValue=e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-cus');
    }     
      });

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

In the above dropdown each value is a link and it has a unique key when clicked on it will route to other section(other page) where data will be displayed using the "keyValue" present in the anchor tag.In this section I use another custom element (element2.html).So how can I pass the keyValue present in element1.html to element2.html

```
<section data-route="site" tabindex="-1">
 <element2></element2> 
</section> 
 element2.html
<dom-module id="my-list">
  <template>   

        <iron-ajax auto
      url="serviceURL/?key={{I need to get the value from element1.html here}}"    
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="handleResponse"
      ></iron-ajax>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Are `element1` and `element2` in same page?

Comment: No both elements are in different page.The element2 should fire an iron-ajax request based on the key passed from the element1...i.e., when I click an option in the dropdown (in the index.html) I need to get the key in element2 page

Comment: Are you using `app-elements` for your project? What i really want to know is that is there a single html file where you place tags for both of these elements, if so then you can share data through bindings(attributes), but in case they are in different html pages all together then you will have to use something like `localStorage`